# NodeJS - Promise callback response [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input]

Tags: node.js, rest, promise, asynccallback, unexpectendoffile

I created the following NodeJS function.

The issue I'm getting is, when I'm executing this code like:

```
someFunc(parameter)
.then(function(doSomething){
  //do something here, which works fine here.
})
//The following function works and is very similar to the next function.
.then(someFunc1)
//
.then(impervaCreateIP)
//
//The following function works and is very similar to the above function.
.then(someFunc3)
.catch(function(e){
  //catch error here. This works too.
})
```

and calling the function below, it's giving me an error:

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input]
```

This error is coming because, when the control goes to **impervaCreateIP()** after function (someFunc1) is successfully complete, then inside *impervaCreateIP()*, the following lines are getting executed (which is waiting for a REST/API call to create a new OS Connection IP in Imperva system).

```
  httpHelp(options, data)
  .then(function(fullResponse){
    var result = JSON.parse(fullResponse[1])
```

As you see above, as soon as httpHelp(options,data).then(function(fullResponse){ ... } section is called, if I print (**console.log("anything")**) just before the following line, it's showing that message fine. BUT, nothing is printed after the following line, reason: **fullResponse[1]** is NOT getting populated or not getting any valid value, by the time the following line is executed async way. This is resulting the program to go directly into the .fail(...){ .. } section and then it's going to someFunc3 (where it's NOT doing anything as exception caught during impervaCreateIP and finally reaching to the .catch(...){ .. } section and doing whatever I'm doing there.

```
    var result = JSON.parse(fullResponse[1])
```

Therefore, the program errors out at the **.parse** for the **.** character i.e. it's not able to PARSE anything for variable **result** as **fullResponse[1]** value is still set to "" (Blank/NULL) and it's yet to be populated.

HOW, can I make my program to wait i.e. until the httpHelp(..).then(function(fullResponse) {.... } is fully done working with the REST/API call and it returns a valid value inside **fullResponse[1]**.

PS: I see fullResponse[0].statusCode == 200, so connection is fine.

**Code:**

```
//Imperva create IP
//qData is a hash array that has valid index/value pair values.
var impervaCreateIP = function(qData){
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var data = '{"connection-mode":"SSH","host-name":"server123.company.com"}'
  var options = {
    hostname: 'myImpervaServerInstance.mycompanydomain.com',
    port: 8083,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/SecureSphere/api/v1/conf/serverGroups/'+ qData['siteName'] + '/' + qData['serverGroupName'] + '/servers/' + qData['ip'],
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
      'X-Requested-With': 'Nodejs',
      'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID='+qData['sid']
    }
  }
  //svtLog() is a logger that I'm using to log messages to a file. Out of scope of this post.
  svtLog('info','Imperva','Inside impervaCreateIP function')
  svtLog('info','Imperva',qData['ip'])
  svtLog('info','Imperva',qData['siteName'])
  svtLog('info','Imperva',qData['serverGroupName'])
  console.log('Inside impervaCreateIP')
  console.log(options);
  httpHelp(options, data)
  .then(function(fullResponse){
    //The following section is not executing
    console.log("00 ---- this will print fine")
    var result = JSON.parse(fullResponse[1])
    //The following section is not executing. It going straight to .catch() as the above line failed at .parse(fullResponse[1]) where fullResponse[1] is coming as BLANK.
    console.log("11 -----")
    console.log(result)
    console.log("22 -----")
    deferred.resolve(qData)
    console.log(result)
  })
  .fail(function(e){
    svtLog('error','Imperva','Failed to add IP in Imperva')
    svtLog('info','Imperva',qData['ip'])
    svtLog('error','Imperva',e)
    svtLog('info','Imperva','')
    deferred.reject(e)
  })
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

**fullResponse** (snapshot of the array value is) in case of someFunc1/3 or ImpervaCreateIP is. I'm showing only the last 5 lines. I have made sure that head -5 for both files looks same and fullResponse[0] index value is mostly similar as well:

```
[vagrant@localhost ws]$ cat -n someFunc1.ip.fullResponse.json |tail -5; echo ----------------; cat -n create.ip.fullResponse.json |tail -5
   230         parser: null,
   231         res: [Circular] },
   232      read: [Function] },
   233    '{"ip":"10.20.30.40","domain":"","connection-mode":"SSH","share-name":"","folder-path":"","user-name":"enter_your_userID","host-name":"test-imperva-clientserver01.cloud.mycompany.com","OS-type":"Linux"}' ]
   234
----------------
   233         parser: null,
   234         res: [Circular] },
   235      read: [Function] },
   236    '' ]
   237
[vagrant@localhost ws]$
```

If you notice, line# 232 and 233 in someFunc1.ip.fullResponse.json file, line# 232 ends fullResponse[0] and line# 233 starts fullResponse[1] values. In my case, lets assume someFunc1 is to find an IP thus, the output above shows, REST/API returned value fullResponse[1] value for finding an IP using Imperva REST/API (where method was GET), rest code is exactly similar to impervaCreateIP().

If you notice, line# 235 and #236 for create.ip.fullResponse.json file, you'll see that line# 235 ends fullResponse[0] array index value and line# 236 starts the value for fullResponse[1] and has a '' (Blank/NULL) in it, which means, while creating an IP using impervaCreateIP, it **DID NOT** receive the valid response from Imperva REST/API in fullResponse[1] array index which is used by

```
var result = JSON.parse(...); // line in my NodeJS code above.
```

Again, the only main different between someFunc1(find an IP) or impervaCreateIP (to create an IP) is, other than that, only console.log("...") message change a bit:

For impervaCreateIP it's set to:

```
method: 'POST',
```

For someFunc1 it's set to:

```
method: 'GET',
```

OK, so it seems like, the issue is with when my **method** is either **POST**/**DELETE** **+** when I'm using **var result = JSON.parse(fullResponse[1])**.

If I don't try to check anything using var result / JSON.parse as mentioned above, my code works fine.

So, I think I the root cause is: fullResponse[1] is NOT getting populated for some reason in case my REST/API HTTP method is either **POST** or **DELETE**. If I **DON'T** use any status checking like what happened after impervaCreateIP(a POST action) **or** during someFunc3(i.e. impervaDeleteSessionID where the method is DELETE), then my program is working fine and my ERROR message goes away.

**BUT, I do want to verify what REST responded back** **for ex**: so that I can catch whether REST connection worked + if create IP action failed due to permission issue for that user whose credentials I used to generate my JSESSIONID. I'm getting the ERROR only when its POST/DELETE and I'm doing JSON.parse(fullResponse[1])

**How can I get the response body in the above NodeJS code, when HTTP method is "POST" or "DELETE" and I want to catch a condition as I mentioned below??** Thanks.

**FYI**:
When I tried the same impervaCreateIP NodeJS logic in a BASH shell script, I wrote the following code and it WORKS!!! as CURL command is returning all the OUTPUT good or bad i.e. with valid response code if there was an error during create IP script creation due to access issue for that user's credentials. **All I'm trying to do** in the NodeJS code is to catch that "**do not have permission**" ERROR which may come if the USER doesn't have enough privileges to CREATE an IP in Imperva system :

```
## Create a new IP OS connection in a given site, server group.
create_ip()
{
 JSESSIONID="${1}"
 addThisIP="${2}"
 siteName="${3}"
 serverGroupName="${4}"
 echo -e "\n- Trying to create a new OS connection IP now.\n";

 ##Make sure while initiating a REST API call, any parameter which has ' ' (space) in Imperva should be substituted with '%20'.
 create_new_ip_output="$(curl -ik -X POST -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=$JSESSIONID" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" "https://${MX}:8083/SecureSphere/api/v1/conf/serverGroups/${siteName// /%20}/${serverGroupName// /%20}/servers/${addThisIP}" -d '{"connection-mode":"SSH","host-name":"thisLinuxServer.fdqn","OS-type":"linux","user-name":"enter_your_userID"}')";
 return_code="$?";
 if [[ "${return_code}" == "0" && ! `echo "${create_new_ip_output}" | grep "do not have permission"` ]]; then
  echo -e "\n\n- OS connection IP (${addThisIP}) created successfully in site: ${siteName}, servergroup: ${serverGroupName} and stdout:\n${create_new_ip_output}\n";
  return 0;
 else
  echo -e "\n\n- Failed to create a new OS connection IP (${addThisIP}) in site: ${siteName} and servergroup: ${serverGroupName}\n- using session ID: ${JSESSIONID}, error log:\n${create_new_ip_output}\n";
  return 1;
 fi
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `fullResponse`? i suspect you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: @KevinB, I'm new and tried couple of solutions online but baffled by why the same is working for someFunc1? Why NodeJS being async n single threaded is waiting for that to complete (when someFunc1) in my case is taking 30 seconds. fullResponse is an array containing 2 indexes, [0].statusCode shows it's successfully making the connection == 200 response code but [1] is coming as ' ' thus, result variable JSON.parse is failing

Comment: I think you are misdiagnosing the problem. If you're seeing status 200, then it is in fact waiting. It is at least waiting for the request to be sent and for the response to begin being received. I have no idea though whether or not httpHelp is coded to properly listen for all of the data chunks and combine them into a proper json string.

Comment: maybe because someFunc1 is coded properly?

Comment: someFunc1 is almost similar to createImpervaIP function. The only thing that's different between someFunc1 and createImpervaIP () is.. the path: line in options variable. someFunc1 (in my case actually is impervaGetSID function and it's working fine, fullResponse[1] populates with valid Session ID and it comes after 20-30 seconds. There's also another function impervaFindIP () exactly same as impervaCreateIP (only method changes from POST to GET).. and it works!. I already have Q module and deffered variable created in my program (I thought that was obvious).

Comment: Sounds like the problem is unrelated to the given code then.

Comment: fullResponse is an object (promise I guess). All I'm trying to find is, why someFunc1, someFunc3 are working while impervaCreateIP is not working for that .parse line. As I mentioned in my previous comment, someFunc1, someFunc3 are exactly similar to impervaCreateIP (only options's path variable or method values are different) among these 3. My understanding is, if httpHelp is not written correctly, then someFunc1 should have failed first. If I comment out .then(impervaCreateIP) line, everything works.

Comment: Not sure if it's due to POST vs GET as someFunc1/someFunc3 are using method: 'GET' but impervaCreateIP( ) is a POST/DELETE HTTP action.

Comment: OK, I think I found the root cause. fullResponse[1] is NOT getting populated for some reason in case method is POST or DELETE, thus, if you DONT use any status checking like what happened after impervaCreateIP(a POST action) or during someFunc3(i.e. impervaDeleteSessionID where the method is DELETE), then it'll WORK fine and my ERROR message goes away. BUT, I do want to verify what REST responds back so that I can catch whether connection worked but create IP failed due to permission issue for that use. I'm getting the ERROR only when its POST/DELETE and I'm doing JSON.parse(fullResponse[1])

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to dive a little deep to answer you why your assumption about "finishing up faster than return" is wrong.

The architecture of javascript does not allow the async callback to be invoked before the return.

javascript has one stack on a single thread, the function gets pushed on the stack, executed, and popped afterwards. you cannot do two things at once on a stack.

when javascript encounters an async operation, it pushes the operation to  another thread through c++ libuv library, then the operation is returned back to javascript on something called a callback queue when the async operation is finished. Things in the event queue are pushed to the stack ONLY when the stack is empty, by the "event loop". hence the return value always executes first, as the function firing the async function is still occupying the javascript stack until a return is encountered and the function is popped off the stack, making it clear and ready to accept things in the callback queue.

Try to log `fullResponse`, see if it has `fullResponse[1]` in the first place.

Comment: Nice explanation. To answer your ? -- Yes, It does. fullResponse[0] is a big JSON kind of object where one of the field is statusCode (coming as 200 in my case), fullResponse[1] is coming as '' (blank) for .then(impervaCreateIP) but the same object: fullResponse[0] and fullResponse[1] are coming with valid values for both .then(someFunc1) and .then(someFunc3) lines/functions if I comment out .then(createImpervaIP) line, everything works then. console.log(fullResponse) shows an array where [0] is always set with some JSON variale/value data and [1] is set with the response from Imperva REST/API

Comment: 1. can you edit your answer to print out the `fullResponse`? place the console.log(fullResponse) right above the var results = ...

2. you are passing qData['sid'] to the next function in the promise chain, not the fullResponse data, so you will not be able to get it there from the parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I copy pasted from my other post. Yes, I'm sending deferred.resolve(qData) instead of qData['sid'] (which I was sending earlier). I'll correct the post. I'll also post what I get in fullReponse as a whole

Comment: try logging fullResponse.body

Comment: For both where fullResponse[1] is good/has valid value and were fullResponse[1] is BLANK/NULL, console.log(fullResponse.body) ... is showing value as "undefined". I also checked for word "body" in whole fullResponse object and this is what I found: In fullResponse[0].req.ClientRequest["_hasBody"] -- shows "true" but that's not what you wanted right?